# Unknown CS1003 Error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I can't compile my project for code-first migrations in entity framework past a certain point. I am reading in values from xml to populate a table. I have the following code:

```
        //EnrolmentProgramStartDate

        var programQuery = from r in context.EnrolmentPrograms
                           select r;

        var programList = programQuery.ToList<Entities.MetaData.Enrolment.EnrolmentProgram>();

        resourceName = "LearnLogicElicos_WebApi.SeedData.MetaData.Enrolment.enrolment_program_start_date.xml";
        stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName);
        xml = XDocument.Load(stream);
        List<Entities.MetaData.Enrolment.EnrolmentProgramStartDate> enrolmentStartdates = new List<Entities.MetaData.Enrolment.EnrolmentProgramStartDate>();

        foreach (var e in xml.Root.Elements("StartDate"))
        {
            DateTime.TryParse((string)e.Element("Start"), out var startDate);

            enrolmentStartdates.Add(new Entities.MetaData.Enrolment.EnrolmentProgramStartDate()
            {
                PrgmCode = (string)e.Element("ProgramCode"),
                StartDate = startDate
            });
        }

        var programStartdateWithFk = (from t1 in enrolmentStartdates
                                      join t2 in programList
                                      on t1.PrgmCode equals t2.PrgmCode
                                      select new Entities.MetaData.Enrolment.EnrolmentProgramStartDate
                                      {
                                          PrgmCode = t1.PrgmCode,
                                          StartDate = t1.StartDate,
                                          EnrolmentProgramFk = t2.PrgmPk
                                      });

        context.EnrolmentProgramStartDates.AddRange(programStartdateWithFk);

        context.SaveChanges();
```

I am getting the following error in the output window: `Configuration.cs(179,71,179,80): error CS1003: Syntax error, ',' expected` but I am not receiving any errors in the error list and I cannot for the life of me see a missing `,`.

The xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Starts>
  <StartDate>
    <ProgramCode>DEC25</ProgramCode>
    <Start>2018,1,2</Start>
  </StartDate>
  <StartDate>
    <ProgramCode>DEC15</ProgramCode>
    <Start>2018,3,19</Start>
  </StartDate>
  <StartDate>
    <ProgramCode>DEC10</ProgramCode>
    <Start>2018,4,30</Start>
  </StartDate>
  <StartDate>
    <ProgramCode>DEC5W</ProgramCode>
    <Start>2018,6,4</Start>
  </StartDate>
  <StartDate>
    <ProgramCode>DEC5R</ProgramCode>
    <Start>2018,6,4</Start>
  </StartDate>
  <StartDate>
    <ProgramCode>DEC5S</ProgramCode>
    <Start>2018,6,4</Start>
  </StartDate>
  <StartDate>
    <ProgramCode>DEC5L</ProgramCode>
    <Start>2018,6,4</Start>
  </StartDate>
  <StartDate>
    <ProgramCode>GE</ProgramCode>
    <Start>2018,1,2</Start>
  </StartDate>
  <StartDate>
    <ProgramCode>GE</ProgramCode>
    <Start>2018,1,8</Start>
  </StartDate>
  <StartDate>
    <ProgramCode>GE</ProgramCode>
    <Start>2018,1,15</Start>
  </StartDate>
  <StartDate>
    <ProgramCode>GE</ProgramCode>
    <Start>2018,1,22</Start>
  </StartDate>
  <StartDate>
    <ProgramCode>GE</ProgramCode>
    <Start>2018,1,29</Start>
  </StartDate>
  <StartDate>
    <ProgramCode>GE</ProgramCode>
    <Start>2018,2,5</Start>
  </StartDate>
  <StartDate>
    <ProgramCode>ITP</ProgramCode>
    <Start>2018,1,2</Start>
  </StartDate>
  <StartDate>
    <ProgramCode>ITP</ProgramCode>
    <Start>2018,1,8</Start>
  </StartDate>
  <StartDate>
    <ProgramCode>ITP</ProgramCode>
    <Start>2018,1,15</Start>
  </StartDate>
  <StartDate>
    <ProgramCode>ITP</ProgramCode>
    <Start>2018,1,22</Start>
  </StartDate>
  <StartDate>
    <ProgramCode>ITP</ProgramCode>
    <Start>2018,1,29</Start>
  </StartDate>
  <StartDate>
    <ProgramCode>ITP</ProgramCode>
    <Start>2018,2,5</Start>
  </StartDate>
</Starts>
```

Could someone please tell me either: a) where the missing comma is, or b) what the real issue leading me to get this error is.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error is on this line:

```
DateTime.TryParse((string)e.Element("Start"), out var startDate);
```

And you get it because of the `var` keyword. You must remove it. It's not clear why you have it there, but if you are trying to declare the variable, then do it on a previous line:

```
DateTime startDate;
DateTime.TryParse((string)e.Element("Start"), out startDate);
```

Having said that, if you wait a while, C# version 7 will actually support this (though it's unclear if you can use `var` instead of an explicit type just yet). Take a look here for the proposed features: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/